# How to Read from a file using a Background Process in Electron App when File is modified?

Tags: uwp, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have an electron app which can be downloaded and installed from `Microsoft store`. I want to attach a background process with the electron app which(`Background Process`) will be monitoring a file. If the file is modified it will read some information from that file and send back to the renderer process.

I took https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-uwp-background as a reference but, unfortunately, not able to build `background-task-registerer` project.
I logged issue https://github.com/felixrieseberg/electron-uwp-background/issues/4

I also referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task but did not get success.

Things I Did:

1. Created a `Background task component`[`Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows)`]
2. Register Background task[`Blank App (Universal Windows)`]

when I double click on Package.appxmanifest and go to the `Declarations` tab->Available Declarations->`Background Tasks`, I do not see any property which is related to file property change.

Is there anyone who can guide me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UWP does not provide such backgroundTask to monitor file property change for long running. I think you could use TimeTrigger to monitor file regularly, But it can only execute once in 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, Do you mean to say that I should use `Timer` Property 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger

In addition to it, does the implementation of reading from a file should be in the `Background task component` ?

Comment: Yep, You could use TimeTrigger  to create backgroundTask, And reading process should be implemented in the Background task component

Comment: Thanks. let me give a try.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  I want to ask a question that is about the same thing, although it isn’t related to this question: is there a way, in UWP, to set a periodic time trigger for a certain background task, deciding WHEN to start the first time?   Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will trigger after you first register successful + timer cycle.

Comment: May I convert above as an answer for this issue If the comments is helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

UWP does not provide such BackgroundTask to monitor file property change for long running. I think you could use [`TimeTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger) to monitor file regularly, But it can only execute once in 15 minutes. And the process should be implemented in the Background task component

Comment: Thanks , I was thinking after every 15 mins when I read data from the file then how would I send this data to the renderer process. Could you please guide me on this ?

Comment: You could send a local toast notification if the file has [changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast)

Comment: I am able to send the tost notification which I can see at the right bottom corner of my screen. but how would I capture in my Electron App.
If I could capture in main process, Then using IPC i can send to renderer process.
If I capture in renderer process then its better. any idea how could I do it ?

Comment: The better way is that store the changes into local storage and retrieve the data when you click the notification.

Comment: But, electron app wont allow to read from the arbitrary path, as in my case its window store app

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) you could store the data in the `LocalFolder`

Comment: We can not use it either, 
`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` returns a `StorageFolder` .So in my case it is 
`C:\Users\kumarpr\AppData\Local\Packages\8d0bb065-b69f-4da1-ba4c-fcd21d312da1_vp9fjm7zssgd8\LocalState`

Comment: Don't you have file access?

Comment: I do have file access. Manually I can create a file

Comment: So, you could log the data in LocalFolder.

Comment: As far as I know we can not use system.io to perform ay operation, since we are in UWP environment so we need to relay on UWP APIs. 
I have create a repository in gitgub
https://github.com/Praveer1981/ElectronBacgroundTaskApp
It would be great if you could help me there. Otherwise our discussion would me never ending :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198286/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-praveer-kumar).

Comment: please use this line to access var `folder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\")`;